# composer.json does not contain a valid json

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

there is a syntax error in my composer.json file but I just can't seem to find the error. I already have a Laravel object on top of the file, but I also want to add Goaop, like the following code.
how can I do it? thank you

```
//newly added code
{
    "name": "goaop/goaop-laravel-bridge",
    "description": "Integration bridge for Go! AOP framework",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": ["bridge", "laravel", "aop", "php", "aspect"],
    "require": {
        "goaop/framework": "^1.0|^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Lisachenko Alexander",
            "email": "lisachenko.it@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Go\\Laravel\\GoAopBridge\\": "./src"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope the `//newly added code` comment is not in your `composer.json` file. JSON cannot contain comments. Other than that, the composer file you posted is valid (this is what Composer says).

Comment: No it is not. I only entered it here

Comment: This is the new library I'm adding. There is another library in the same file with a "name", "keyword" etc. But when I add this new one, the file is invalid

Comment: That JSON is valid, do you get an error somewhere saying it isn't? If so please add the error here

Comment: https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/id=49e6e6c2989c0ec8f4540322dd301117&fullscreen/

Comment: If you want to add another dependency to your project, use [`composer require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require). For most changes regarding `composer.json` there is no need to manually edit the file. Composer provides commands for almost all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just copied the [package's `composer.json`](https://github.com/goaop/goaop-laravel-bridge/blob/master/composer.json) and pasted it to the bottom of yours. That is not how you install packages.

From your command line run:

```
composer require goaop/goaop-laravel-bridge
```

This will update your composer.json and .lock files and install the package.